# Simple LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, select, linq-to-xml

In C#, how can I select values from an XML file using LINQ?

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Level1>
<Level2>
    <Value1>This-is-value-1</Value1>
    <Value2>This-is-value-2</Value2>
    <Value3>This-is-value-3</Value3>
    <Value4>This-is-value-4</Value4>
</Level2>  
</Level1>
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
var values = from lv1 in doc.Descendants("level1")
            from lvl2 in lv1.Descendants("Level2")
            select new {
                Value1 = lv1.Attribute("Value1").Value,
                Value2 = lv1.Descendants("Value2").Value,
                Value3 = lv1.Descendants("Value3").Value,
                Value4 = lv1.Descendants("Value4").Value,
            };
```

I am wanting to retrieve the following values:

- Value1
- Value2
- Value3
- Value4

May I please have some help to get this working?

**EDIT**

Sorry, I meant to add that I would like to place the values in local fields.

E.g. Here are the field names:

```
string Value1;
string Value2;
string Value3;
string Value4;
```

May I have some help to place the values from the LINQ statement into the local fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are various things wrong with your current code:

- You're using `Attribute` when there aren't attributes in the XML
- You're trying to use the `Value` property on `Descendants`, but `Descendants` returns `IEnumerable<XElement>`
- You're not using `lv2` anywhere
- You're looking for `level1` as an element name rather than `Level1`. (XML is case-sensitive.)

I suspect you just want:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
var values = from level in doc.Descendants("Level1").Descendants("Level2")
             select new {
                 Value1 = (string) level.Element("Value1"),
                 Value2 = (string) level.Element("Value2"),
                 Value3 = (string) level.Element("Value3"),
                 Value4 = (string) level.Element("Value4")
             };
```